# Image preview script breaks on uploading the same image that was previously deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-filer

I am using this [package](http://filer.grandesign.md/#documentation), and I have modified it a bit, so that I can upload, drag and sort the images and preview them in the browser. Uploading works fine, and deleting of images. But I found a scenario when the script breaks. When I have more than one image and I delete the first image, on trying to upload the same image that I deleted the script doesn't work anymore. But if I don't try to upload the same image immediately and first upload some other and then the one that was deleted, then it works. Also, I don't get any errors in the console. I am not sure how to fix this.

My full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t338ubga/1/).

This is part of the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var imageCounter = 0;

    $('#articleForm').submit(function () {
        uploadPosition();
    });

    function uploadPosition() {
        var uploadedImagesPositions = [];
        $.each($('.jFiler-item-thumb-image'), function (index, value) {
            $(this).attr('data-position-index', index);
            uploadedImagesPositions[index] = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        });

        if (!$('input[name="uploadedItems"]').length) {
            $('<input>', {
                type: "hidden",
                name: "uploadedItems"
            }).appendTo('#articleForm')
        }
        $('input[name="uploadedItems"]').val(JSON.stringify(uploadedImagesPositions));
        $("input[name^='jfiler-items-exclude-']:hidden").detach();
        console.log(uploadedImagesPositions);
    }

    $('#upload').filer({
        limit: null,
        maxSize: null,
        extensions: null,
        changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><h1>+</h1></div>',
        showThumbs: true,
        appendTo: '.uploaded_items',
        theme: "default",
        templates: {
            box: '<div class="jFiler-item-list"></div>',
            item: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container dragdiv"></div>',
            itemAppend: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container dragdiv"></div>',
            progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
            itemAppendToEnd: false,
            removeConfirmation: false,
            _selectors: {
                list: '.jFiler-item-list',
                item: '.jFiler-item',
                progressBar: '.bar',
                remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action',
            }
        },
        uploadFile: {
            url: "/admin/articles/ajax",
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (data, el) {
                uploadedImagesPositions = [];
                console.log(data);
                var filenameArray = data.split('/');
                var name = filenameArray.slice(-1).pop();
                var filename = name.replace(/[\/\s()]/g, '');

                var imageContainer = $('[data-jfiler-index="' + imageCounter + '"]').first();

                $('<div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="/imagecache/thumb/' + filename + '"></div><div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a></div>').appendTo(imageContainer);
                imageCounter++;

                $(".dragdiv").each(function () {
                    makeElementAsDragAndDrop($(this));
                });

                $('.images-refresh').hide();
                $('.images-refresh').click(function () {
                    $(this).closest("form").submit()
                });

                function makeElementAsDragAndDrop(elem) {
                    $(elem).draggable({
                        revert: "invalid",
                        cursor: "move",
                        helper: "clone"
                    });
                    $(elem).droppable({
                        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            uploadedImagesPositions = [];
                            $('.images-form a').hide();
                            $('.images-refresh').show();
                            var $dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                            $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                            makeElementAsDragAndDrop(this);
                            makeElementAsDragAndDrop($dragElem);
                        }
                    });
                }

                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            error: function (el) {
                console.log(el);
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            statusCode: {},
            onProgress: function () {},
        },
        dragDrop: {
            dragEnter: function () {},
            dragLeave: function () {},
            drop: function () {},
        },
        addMore: true,
        clipBoardPaste: true,
        excludeName: null,
        beforeShow: function () {
            return true
        },
        onSelect: function () {},
        afterShow: function () {},
        onRemove: function (el) {
            imageCounter = $('.img-container').size() - 1;
            //uploadPosition();
            //console.log(el.find('img').attr('src'));
        },
        onEmpty: function () {
            imageCounter = 0;
        },
        captions: {
            button: "Choose Files",
            feedback: "Choose files To Upload",
            feedback2: "files were chosen",
            drop: "Drop file here to Upload",
            removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?",
            errors: {
                filesLimit: "Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesType: "Only Images are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesSize: "{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
                filesSizeAll: "Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Update**

I have updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq0cy7sd/1/) with HTML and CSS as well as javascript code, unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work, so not sure how helpful it is, but at least you can see the full code.
I am using this scripts on my page where I upload images:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/foundation/foundation.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-filer/jquery-filer.js') }}"></script>
```

`jquery-filer` is the script that I use for upload, the one that I have in fiddle.

And this is my server-side function for ajax upload. I am using PHP laravel in the backend:

```
public function ajaxUpload() {

    if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $files = Input::file('file');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $time = microtime(true);
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = $time.'-'.preg_replace('/[(\)\s]/u', '', $name);

            if(substr($file->getMimeType(), 0, 5) == 'image') {

                try {
                    $original = Image::make($file)->save(public_path($this->destinationPath.'/'.$filename));
                    \Log::info('try: '.$filename."\n");

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    \Log::info('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage(). "\n");
                }

                $img = Image::cache(function($image) use ($original){
                    return $image->make($original);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->destinationPath.$filename;
}
```

Comment: Any errors from the server or in the console?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Is it possible image is being cached on delete?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check that? @yardpenalty

Comment: In firefox you can type `about:cache` in your url and then click on the `List Cache Entries` link.

Comment: I used `chrome://cache/` and I didn't find any image entries from my project

Comment: Can you cut the problem down and make a fiddle that suffers the issue? A running fiddle is the shortest route to a solution for you and I guess you are keen to find an answer since you set a bounty. So do a bit more work for us and you will be helping yourself to an earlier answer.

Comment: Please include the full working example, with html and preferably css, with minimal code to help detecting what part of your code might be wrong. Right now, it seems like the options you provide for filer is too bloated and it is hard to see the actual problem.

Comment: Since I do not see the full code, making and assumption here, I had this same issue with Javascript and Laravel. The problem was that when the image was deleted from the frontend, it has to be deleted from the disk as well via Laravel, in the function that handles deletion of image.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to salvage the problem part in your code and came up with this ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirkurt53/1tc1ocku/)).

The problem part is probably in the `success` function. Instead of trying to get element by its index, use the 2nd argument passed to the `success` function.

```
success: function(data, el) {
  uploadedImagesPositions = [];
  var filenameArray = data.split('/');
  var name = filenameArray.slice(-1).pop();
  var filename = name.replace(/[\/\s()]/g, '');

  // Instead of this
  // var imageContainer = $('[data-jfiler-index="' + imageCounter + '"]').first();

  // Use this
  var imageContainer = el;

  $('<div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="/imagecache/thumb/' + filename + '"></div><div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a></div>').appendTo(imageContainer );
}
```

The problem could also be caused by your server side, which we have no access right now.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I kept getting the same thing, I just can't upload the same image immediately after I have delete it, only if I upload some other image first, then I can upload the same again. And also, that is not happening at the first time when I try to upload deleted image again, it works the first time ever, but then after that for every image after the first one, I can't upload the same image again immediately after deleting it first

Comment: @Marco What is not working for you? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Can you confirm the file is created on the server, or the server side code runs when file is selected? Also I asked you to trim the code but you added even more code.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know where to trim, since I have no idea, which part of the code is causing this issue. I can confirm that on the server side everything works fine. I am previewing images on upload, and that works fine, I also have feature, that I can remove images in the preview, and that also works fine, the only issue is that if I remove some image, I can't upload again immediately that same one, I need to first upload some other image and the I can upload that same one again.

Comment: @Marco Yeah but why do you think you can't upload the image? Is the front end preview not shown? Is the image image not generated on the server side? Is there an error message? You keep telling it is not working but there must be something indicating that it is not working. To trim the code, first try with `jQuery.filer`'s default settings, without templates and all the cosmetic stuff. For example, where you assign `null` in options, these are completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/ (jQuery.filer was transfered to the Fileuploader)

Answer (score 0):

I was also using a JS image uploader which has the same type of issue. When a user uploads an image and deletes it and uploads the same image again, it does not work. 
So I fixed it using:

`$('input[type="file"]').val(null);`

in the image deleted event.